# Iterating over the BasicBlocks of loops of function in LLVM IR in module pass

Tags: llvm, llvm-ir, llvm-c++-api

does anybody know how to iterate over the basic of Loops of functions in module pass.I was trying :

```
bool runOnModule(Module &M) override
{
    for(Module::iterator f = M.begin(), fend = M.end(); f != fend; ++f)
    {
            LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>().getLoopInfo();
            for(Loop *L : LI)
            {
                for(BasicBlock *BB : L->getBlocks())
                {
                    dbgs() << "basicb name: "<< BB->getName() <<"\n";
                }
            }
     }
     return true;
}
```

and it always gives the error

```
opt: /home/anurag/polly/llvm/include/llvm/PassAnalysisSupport.h:235:    AnalysisType& llvm::Pass::getAnalysisID(llvm::AnalysisID) const [with AnalysisType = llvm::LoopInfoWrapperPass; llvm::AnalysisID = const void*]: Assertion `ResultPass && "getAnalysis*() called on an analysis that was not " "'required' by pass!"' failed.
```

Comment: Have you added the LoopInfoWrapperPass to your getAnalysisUsage() routine?

Comment: yes i have added.

Comment: @Brian I tried like:void getAnalysisUsage(AnalysisUsage &AU) const override {
                        AU.addRequired<LoopInfoWrapperPass>();
                }

Answer (score 0):

There are two updates needed for this code.  The first was also noted in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26005875/llvm-error-accessing-loopinfo-in-function-pass?rq=1), that when requesting the loop info from a module pass, you need to specify the function (adding the iterator access):

```
LoopInfo &LI = getAnalysis<LoopInfoWrapperPass>(*f).getLoopInfo();
```

The second issue is that some functions in the module are "empty", declarations without definitions.  Adding a check for the size should skip those and avoiding any issues with trying to find loops in empty functions.

```
if ((*f).size() == 0) continue;
```